# What is reserved memory in YARN and why it shows spike?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, emr, amazon-emr

I have a doubt around what exactly is reserved memory in YARN?
I do understand that its YARN's way of balancing the memory requirement raised by several jobs that are submitted, so that no job goes in starvation mode. It tries to reserve the memory as and when it is freed up for another job.

We use AWS EMR for our operations. I have observed that at times when a memory intensive job is submitted on our cluster(say spark-sql job) 1TB ram gets reserved out of our total 3TB RAM. **I have observed this even when just one job is submitted/running on the cluster** and none other are waiting or queued up.
This spike in memory is observed intermittently at times in range of 5-15 mins and then comes down to manageable level or even 0.

Can someone please explain if this is normal behavior or not. If its normal please explain it in little details. Else if there is some probable configuration mistake that can trigger this please help me in resolving this.

Note -> We have R4 8xlarge 10 node cluster on EMR 5.0.0.

Thanks in advance

Manish Mehra

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Memory reserved on Yarn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566468/what-is-memory-reserved-on-yarn)

Comment: No they aren't duplicate I am experiencing this even when just one job is running on the cluster.

Comment: Hi, we have same issues, did you manage to find out a cause?

Comment: @OleksiiDuzhyi - No not really!!