# yarn top command explained

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Can someone explain output of this `yarn top` command? I mean what exactly those shortcuts (#CONT #RCONT VCORES RVCORES MEM RMEM VCORESECS MEMSECS %PROGR TIME NAME) mean and how the numbers are calculated?

Answer (score 9):

I have the same question, so searched in the code base and find [TopCLI.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/client/cli/TopCLI.java#L150).

```
APPID     | ApplicationId of the application, e.g. application_1614636765551_1548
USER      | user e.g. hadoop
TYPE      | application's Type,  e.g. spark
QUEUE     | to which the application was submitted
PRIORITY  | Application's priority, e.g. 0=VERY_HIGH, see JobPriority.java
CONT      | the number of used containers
RCONT     | the number of reserved containers
VCORES    | the used Resource - virtual cores
RVCORES   | the reserved Resource - virtual cores
MEM       | the used Resource - memory in GB
RMEM      | the resevered Resource - memroy in GB
VCORESECS | the aggregated number of vcores that the application has allocated times the number of seconds the application has been running.
MEMSECS   | the aggregated amount of memory (in megabytes) the application has allocated times the number of seconds the application has been running.
PROGRESS  | application's progress
TIME      | application running time in "dd:HH:mm"
NAME      | application name
```

Comment: and the meaning of `reserved`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566468/what-is-memory-reserved-on-yarn